# How to all field value pass in payload when record update in direct us

Tags: payload, directus-flows

I want to all data pass in payload when data update in direct us.

Example:  When I data update any record. I am getting only that data which is update.
But I need to all field. in payload flows.

I need flow in all field. You can see the screenshot of flow.
[image: Flow]

and second screenshot about the payload which I data update.
[image: Trigger]

I have only one field update and that is status. So I am get status field in payload. But I need to all field in payload. Because I need id of user so I can send notification send to the user

Comment: This seems to be machine translated to English. Please try other translators, and have two different translators translate the result back to the original language to get an impression of translation quality.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this:

1. Create a new "read data" operation after the trigger setup.
   Configure this to read data from the updated collection and add this `{{$trigger.keys[0]}}` under IDs so that it reads the data for the last updated record only.
2. Create the "update data" operation which will happen if the read data operation is successful.
   On the payload, use the "id" for the read data operation as follows:

   ```
    {
      "field_a_update": "{{read_data_id.field_a_updated}}",
      "field_b_update": "{{read_data_id.field_b_updated}}"
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Way Easier:

1. Create a new "read data" operation after the trigger setup. Configure this to read data from the updated collection and add this {{$trigger.keys[0]}}.
2. In send Email you can use key from "read data" operation:

{{key_operation.your_field_name}}

example - {{item_read_xbh4n.id}}